# Como passar os dados de um Dataset para uma planilha Excel C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Eu li sheet por sheet de uma planílha, e armazenei em um *DataSet*. Estou com dificuldade de passar para outra planílha esses dados do *DataSet*. Alguém pode me ajudar ? **Tenho o segunte código:**

```
 conn.Open();
                string strConexao = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0\"", localArquivo);
                DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                DataSet output = new DataSet();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    // obtem o noma da planilha corrente
                    string sheet = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    // obtem todos as linhas da planilha corrente
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    // copia os dados da planilha para o datatable
                    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable(sheet);
                    output.Tables.Add(outputTable);
                    new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(outputTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Procure usar o EPPlus para isso](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/). Mais simples.

```
using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Leandro Diaz";
    excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Minha Planilha";

    foreach (DataTable table in SuasTables)
    {
        var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(table.TableName);
        sheet.Name = table.TableName;

        // Títulos
        var i = 1;
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            sheet.Cells[1, i++].Value = column;
        }

        var rowIndex = 2;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            var col = 1;
            foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
            {
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = row[column].ToString();
            }

            rowIndex++;
        }
    }

    string path = @"C:\teste.xlsx";
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
}
```